# Unable to set innerHTML from HTML Collection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I have below div tag from material UI which is getting autogenerated through MUI -

```
<div class="MuiAvatar-root.MuiAvatar-circular.MuiAvatar-colorDefault">Some Text</div>
```

Through javascript , I am fetching this element as -

```
var ele=document.getElementsByClassName("MuiAvatar-root MuiAvatar-circular MuiAvatar-colorDefault");
console.log(ele);
```

In console log I am able to see element with all its properties including `innerHTML` as `Some Text`

When I am trying to change the InnerHTML by -

`ele[0].innerHTML="Changed Text"` , I am not able to see that text got changed.

Also , before this , when I try to log innerHTML -

`console.log(ele[0].innerHTML)` , I am getting blank result.

How can I change the inner HTML from HTML Collection I am fetching ?

Comment: Typo. should be [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Also you should then iterate them like in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed two things:

1. Typo in getElementsByClassName -> should be `getElementByClassName`
2. If you put spaces in your class name inside `getElementsByClassName`  like `MuiAvatar-root MuiAvatar-circular`, its not correct.

```js
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("MuiAvatar-root.MuiAvatar-circular.MuiAvatar-colorDefault");

ele[0].innerHTML = "TEST"
```

```html
<div class="MuiAvatar-root.MuiAvatar-circular.MuiAvatar-colorDefault">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: I am getting ele as HTML collection with one element within. But ele[0] as undefined . Even I replaced space with dots

Comment: Can you try `[].forEach.call(ele, function (el) { console.log(el)});` and let me know what do you get